# Important Stoichiometry question, just need formula or help and answer checking

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stoichiometry

How many grams of Cobalt(II) chloride  $\ce{CoCl2}$ is needed to make $\pu{0.645 L}$ with a concentration of $\pu{1.25  mol\:L^{-1}}$? (the molar mass of anhydrous $\ce{CoCl2}$ is $\pu{129.839 g\: mol^{-1}}$, I believe)

Comment: This is definitely a homework question. You must need to show your effort to solve it.

Comment: well, could you show me the formula possibly? I don't know how to get help with this question and I don't know how to do it...

Comment: First, you need to find the amount of $\ce{CoCl2}$ in $\pu{mols}$ to make $\pu{0.645 L}$ of $\pu{1.25 M}$ solution.

Comment: I believe it is .807, what do I do after this?

Comment: Correct answer is $\pu{0.806 mol}$. So, do you remember, $g= \pu{mol} \times \text{molar mass}$?

Comment: yes, what do i do with the .806

Answer (score 1):

Remember the formula $c = \frac{n}{v}$ where $c$ is the molarity, which is moles of solute per liter of solution. You can rearrange it to get $c \times v = n$. Thus in your case $\pu{1.25M} \times \pu{0.645L} = \pu{0.806 mol}$.

With this information, you can convert moles to grams by multiplying the moles by the molar mass. Thus, $\pu{0.806mol} \times \pu{129.839 \frac{g}{mol}}$ which equals $\pu{104.68 g}$. This is your answer.